# How do I convert larger negative decimals to binary ? For example -513

Tags: binary, decimal

I tried to solve using the following approach: 
- convert absolute value to binary.
- do 2's complement.
but the problem that I came across is how many bits should I use to represent absolute value of 513 ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement

From wikipedia, a binary number of N bits can represent between −2^(N-1) to +2^(N − 1) − 1

Where 2^X is 2 power of X.

There isn't much sense to ask how many bits are required to represent 513. You can represent it with a single bit where 1 represent 513 and 0 something else.
You need to ask how many bits do I need to represent a range of numbers.

As I mentioned above, with 2's complement you can represent up to (2^(N-1)-1) positive numbers and 2^(N-1) negative numbers.
So assuming you want to represent [-513..513] you would need 11 bits.

That is because 2^(11-1) equals 1024. This way you will be able to represent numbers from -1024 up to 1023 in 2's complement.
Choosing N = 10 would give you numbers between -512 and up to 511 which is not enough.

I hope this helps.